# Projector problem on New Catalina OS

Tags: macos, catalina, projector

I upgraded my *MacOS* to *10.15.1* which is the **MacOS Catalina**.

Before this I was able to use our **Epson EX7235 Projector**. But when it was upgraded it no longer works. Thus I downloaded new driver for the Catalina version. For a month there was none but lately they already have one. So, I was happy to install it.

The installation was very easy however the problem is only the screensaver is showing and not my actual screen. I search online and most of the advice is to go *System Preferences* then *Display* and then check the **Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available** which of course I did. However, it still did not work. So, uninstalled again the latest driver installer and re-install again but with the same result.

Hoping to hear similar problem as mine with solutions.

Comment: Have you contacted Epson Support?  This sounds like a bug with their driver.

Comment: @Allan No I haven't yet. I will probably at some point. My projector is no longer under warranty. I am also living in a tiny island nation of Federated States of Micronesia in Western Pacific. Thank you for your suggestion by the way.